# I created the command Ctrl-E to run all cells in Jupyter notebook, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to run all cells in Jupyter notebook with python.
There are 2 ways to do so: (1) click on "cell" then "run all". or (2) create a keyboard shortcut: "Ctrl-E" (or anything else). But both (1) and (2) don't work.

It looks line the cells are running because in the [] there is a [*] for a split second, so it is trying to run but doesn't run. there are no errors, it just doesn't run.

When I run one cell at a time, it works but I obviously don't want to do that.

Comment: Is "Kernel->restart & run all" working for you?

Comment: No, I just tried and it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I think after hitting the run all cell or Ctrl-E, if any cell code have an error then jupyter notebook will not run below cell. So solving the error or markdown the cell can solve the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).